# Converting a file from FileChooser to a string in Java

Tags: java, file-io, jfilechooser, typeconverter

This is my first time using JFileChooser in Java and I'm currently attempting to convert the selected folder from a file type to a string such that I can write it to a JTextField on the GUI automatically so the user can confirm what they have selected.

The section of code I'm working on is as follows:

```
JButton btnSel1 = new JButton("Select...");
    btnSel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                fol1 = fc.getFileAsString(file);
                rawIn1.setText(fol1);
            }   
        }
    });
    welFrame.getContentPane().add(btnSel1, "6, 6, center, default");
```

Where I want the variable 'fol1' (folder 1) to be written into the JTextField 'rawIn1'.

The method getFileAsString returns the the error "is undefined for the type JFileChooser"

Thanks in advance to anyone who looks over this for me.

Jared.

Comment: There's no such method, which is what it's telling you. You can't just make them up.

Comment: *"so the user can confirm what they have selected."* The file-chooser has an open(/save) & **cancel* button.  Why does the user need to confirm the file choice again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `getFileAsString` method in `JFileChooser`. You should use

```
rawIn1.setText(file.getName());
```

or

```
rawIn1.setText(file.getPath());
```

As the example in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you would probably want to use `File.getPath()` or `File.getName()` if you only want the last part of the file name.